# Jenkins OutOfMemory Exception with different routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jenkins, deployment

i'm having a big problem when try to build on jenkins 
This exception is due to a routing convention

When using this

```
[HttpPost, Route(@"{appName:regex(^[A-Za-z0-9, ]+$)}/{moduleName:regex(^[A-Za-z0-9, ]+$)?}")]
```

although on my local it works, when try to deploy on jenkins it fails to build the project

either i get this

> Unhandled Exception: OutOfMemoryException.
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9):
>   error MSB6006: "csc.exe" exited with code 255.
>   [D:\Jenkins\jobs\ReleaseNotes-Test\workspace\ECM.ReleaseNotes.WebApi.csproj]
>   Done Building Project
>   "D:\Jenkins\jobs\ReleaseNotes-Test\workspace\ECM.ReleaseNotes.WebApi.csproj"
>   (PublishToFileSystem target(s)) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.

or

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The
>   paging file is too small for this operation to complete. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x800705AF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting server is one way to fix it but if it persists this could be due to Low amount of memory allocated to your jenkins... In that case use the following link to increase the amount of memory given to Jenkins.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Builds+failing+with+OutOfMemoryErrors

Answer (score 0):

it appeared that the problem was the server. After restarting i was able to make the deploy.